# Appium: Turn off "Check for Updates" through command line

Tags: command-line, selenium-webdriver, appium

The GUI version of Appium has a toggle in the General Settings where you can turn off Automatic Updates Check at startup.

Is there an equivalent for those who run Appium through command line (using Node.js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, npm does not update Appium automatically, unless you've configured your npm install to do so.

If you'd like better control of your Appium versions, but would still like to run Appium from the command line, I suggest using: `appium-version-manager`

[Installation instructions](https://www.npmjs.org/package/appium-version-manager)

Usage Example:

```
avm 1.2.0 # Download Appium version 1.2.0
avm use 1.2.0 # Launch Appium version 1.2.0
avm use 1.2.0 --app /path/to/app --force-iphone # Launch with capabilities

avm 1.2.3 # Download Appium version 1.2.3
avm use 1.2.3 # Launch 1.2.3
```

Comment: Seriously avm is wonderful. The only problem is it doesn't like spaces in its command line arguments! (even if they're escaped) :(

Comment: Oh yeah? Didn't know that - I was just worried that the CL version might update without me knowing it and something might stop working, so I thought best to turn it off altogether, but avm does sound useful. Offtopic - but are you one of the contributors to Appium on github?

Comment: I don't believe it will update automatically. I'm like 98% sure. And I am not. I do submit issues occasionally, but I don't know much JS. I think I might be one of the few that uses python.